# Relational-JSON overlapping with association

Tags: postgresql, normalization, json, psql

I have a composed class called `sensor` that is linked to a main class `Node` such that:

- class `node` is linked with another `node` to make a communication that produce an `event`
- class `sensor` can as well detect `event`s

So I thought of putting the `sensor` data inside of the table `node` as a JSON, but the  association that allows me to detect makes doesn't apply to any schema I have seen before.

Is it a good idea to make the change that way or will that be more tricky to get the needed data?

See the full UML below; but my point concerns only the `sensor`.

**Do you think I can convert that in R-JSON?**

If you spot any place other than position that it would be suited to use R-JSON, I would like to think of the option.

[image: http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/png/TLPjRzis4FukGF_Xe7vOqyP1tNLRAWn3FTS3WYrfa6RzKXG2JLri8XBfKNGM8_D_t_7Eb2rd2vnOF3wyUtWlZ_AX2yg7TTlaMPvz1zUJcydbx7PsypdFkdjZLygh5XfZCMnM22lNREBYFpUT3qiNtUHPCA51g5LGC5STmWCkZLwJAJWmziwhBgmz0dnvUn7XAwNlrGAXcBfsvJfbGm4lpd-QpcQ_mbEUgNaNlD81TAEw3gvSZT4Cy5hLTTMXxPn_UG8bF3XJivtWjhj3dpQlngKydLwztJsTb20Fm2TgR7fFfVZPvbaCLOmBU3KQGV7cxEpLwPZ-5Ft1F9io9J489rfuevhAhbkYP6mGQqkk6ZBGLOnT0BlFCxdHXQJ4hpMdHVoO6g2au_2qjkQlDH8UuYzzKhvQDpSDLZfb3LwyE__-upadJJn_IOdV-MnRHV79ee9nTiyH5-WPqIfFiGvvHkCnzvXwxshY6xriK7dQfN9Zt1AUmfG-GkJI1SSSuBLMnD-4pI3ojaV6DDmBT8-jMlNuFtXDmPyudaJTcojgLwFbxjlXpftns2hBORRIiupWtYguo40bfzAp9SzUnkzJNft0sHbGfxPK5yrv77RmtavT_6xyu_lPc2b8z05WLvOuFh6A1nib3DRLBK648yQYFTyKLyvY5LpbB1wiwA8RFYljCvWuV42Uje_yCvYs7M569AAcHHACTWLbgZRrQKK04_2eaxIZnK7xGXdmCJ09laBIX2hUdjr_lfvDBoP_LDF9JLpUtlmv_Jq-N7ww_HI_sRvDhQsqDlMUsiAh1sgK8GVhsZcfG2y_krqlp0SCliQYVuiYScYj1dFwDwgm97-gGP_YIdhIR4YMi5sXLppB1tma--A9nb1KeiQ0kc-5L20GVUW7lMYSLetfKbVzyDlxsUJDViolNMSE-gbnTc72kexXxngdH8BYp1yQXneaVKcQB2wiQd5uAvAOG8IrguUt8ZVfR9oNqQYWsUa9bG1pZ7owgFsYg157i77HemY6ZwOB7Vdb530nnlxy3sdliK8EzdgDexSIwx3GWCWZLKVI725YuPEfWmR6GOq7Eyzh5adsqHb3sf9dHsH7NvUcfZZVHh_iNXGoWyzFHv4yjh4S9XxnIYFHfPJp4fnU-rtY6CnlAiumeJLByz8rTPVgb2IcVx6DTtagOSMYZiBj0zgQ_Z7u5m00]

Comment: I have to use R-JSON but based  on the imbrication model there is no case where the class to be integrating in the main class have an association with event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want simple and efficient SQL statements, don't model an entity as a JSON column. Create a regular normalized table that expresses the functional dependency between the sensor's attributes explicitly.

JSON in the database is a good thing and has its applications, but modeling foreign key relationships like the one to `event` is not among them.

Comment: where will be the correct place to apply R-JSON  with this conception then , I already did make a sql with a BCNF normalisation I can join in if you want , but I need to make it easy to erase communications from a certain sensor ( might be disabled )

Comment: Why that insistence on R-JSON? I don't get the point.

Comment: This is an assignment so the teacher want us to use it, but won't that make it easier from an application perspective (via web )

Comment: In my understanding, R-JSON provides JSON functionalities to R, but that doesn't necessarily mean that you have to use JSON in the database. Perhaps the `event` data could passed to the application in JSON form? Then R-JSON might make processing easier.

Comment: won't that make the same probleme as event has also a link with sensor

Comment: I don't know. I was just giving a random example that the structure of the data in your application need not be the same as in the database.

Comment: So to make things straight I can't integrate any class having other foreign key relationship other than the composition inside another one , knowing that it wouldn't also folow 1NF?

Comment: what about the data types communication_type and vehicule_type ,I would use that as JSON or it's not  doable ? I already use a  view to manage the content of some attributs based  on the type in communication

Comment: I won't scrutinize your complete project. Sure, you could get JSON into that database. The question is if that makes sense or if that is what your teacher wants.

Comment: it's okay I'll try to put arguments to explain that I can't use R-JSON in order to make it easier to query the base , as in this case it's more of burden then

Comment: but I would like to have an idea about the forced option I have IF I want to use R-JSON ?

Comment: What has R-JSON to do with JSON in the database?

Comment: ain't R-JSON the fact of integrating a table as JSON and use the provided methods that would query it as if it it was a  json content but keeping the relational aspect of the data base